# Linking Cairo (installed with homebrew) on Silicon Apple M2

Tags: homebrew, cairo, pkg-config

I am trying to build a Go program which uses `github.com/ungerik/go-cairo` as a Cairo wrapper in Go. I built it successfully for several months and then it suddenly stopped working. Unfortunately, I don't know how my system has changed.

### Build command:

`go build -o=/tmp/bin/api ./cmd/api`

### Error:

```
# github.com/ungerik/go-cairo
/Users/jan/go/pkg/mod/github.com/ungerik/go-cairo@v0.0.0-20210317133935-984b32e6bac6/cairo.go:6:11: fatal error: 'cairo/cairo-pdf.h' file not found
 #include <cairo/cairo-pdf.h>
```

I have tried to debug it further by checking the following output:

### Output of cmd: `pkg-config --cflags cairo-pdf`

```
-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cairo/1.18.0/include -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cairo/1.18.0/include/cairo
```

### Output of cmd: `which -a pkg-config`

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/pkg-config`
```

There is also an existing issue on Github:
https://github.com/ungerik/go-cairo/issues/16

I have already tried the solution of running: `xcode-select --install`
But I still get the same error.

Can you help me debug it further?